# How to mutualize listen parameters for the same address:port pair in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I’m trying to deploy different websites on the same server that all listen on `0.0.0.0:443` with HTTP/2. My Ansible template looks like this:

```
# This is deployed in /etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ domain }}.conf and symlinked in sites-enabled
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 reuseport;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 reuseport;
  server_name {{ domain }};

  ...
}
```

This doesn’t work because according to the [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) (emphasis mine):

> **The listen directive can have several additional parameters** specific to socket-related system calls. These parameters can be specified in any listen directive, **but only once for a given address:port pair**.

If I were deploying these websites by hand I would use `listen 443 ssl http2 reuseport;` in the first one and then `listen 443;` in the subsequent ones. But I’m trying to simplify the setup by having a single Ansible template that I can use for any website.

It looks cumbersome to check if there’s already a deployed website with these options and don’t include them if that’s the case. Also, if I remove the website with these options, it breaks all the others.

Is there any way I could add a unique file somewhere under `/etc/nginx` that says "use these parameters on `0.0.0.0:443`" for all `listen` directives? I could probably add a dummy `server{}` block somewhere than listens for a unexisting server name but I wonder if there’s a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I have for now:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/http2 -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/http2
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 reuseport;
    server_name --;
}
```

`--` is a dummy server name that doesn’t match anything. This block serves only as a common place for the `listen` parameters.

Now I just deploy websites with `listen 443;` and no other parameter, and they all share that common config.